# how to make language independent database connection b.w VS 10 and sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asmx

I have a database in SQL server 2008 r2 and I want to connect it with my site with the help of visual studio( using .net application)

Now the issue is that I want to create a web service that connects my db with my application but this connection should be language independent like it can be used by any client(not only use by .net client).

initially I have created a web service with the code below:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Get all questions from question_options table")]
public DataSet GetLatestCustomers()
{
    string str = "Data Source=MUNEEBA-PC;Initial Catalog=quizdb;Integrated Security=True";
     using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (str))   
     {
         string Query = "SELECT * FROM [question_options] for xml auto ";
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);

        connection.Open();

        XmlReader rdr;
        rdr = (XmlReader)command.ExecuteXmlReader();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(rdr, XmlReadMode.Fragment);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        return ds;
```

but this doesn't seems to be effective.

Comment: how is the connection limited to a programming language?

Comment: means connection and transportation of data should be language independent.. it should be done through xml

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Also, why are you writing legacy ASMX services? Are you using .NET 2.0?

Comment: @Muneeba Mujeeb I just want to confirm i got it rigth: You want to have a webservice, which can be used by any client to obtain xmldata from your DB?

Comment: yes it can be used by any client to obtain sql data from DB.. my data is not in the form of XML..

Comment: @John Saunders nope i m using .net 4.0

Comment: @Muneeba Mujeeb you could pass the data by writing a TCP-Server with a custom set of commands. But why arent you using the native connection of the DB?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: You need to make your method restful which is quite simple check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services). This simple thing allow you to call and grab data from any language. I have made Android app, PHP and ASP (classic) calling ASMX restful and WCF Restful perfectly in the past

Comment: @Franck: he _needs_ to make the method restful? There's no other way to do it? How do you know that would solve his problem, _considering that he did not tell us what his problem is_?

Comment: One thing you should do if you want your code to be independent of the client technology used is to not use platform-specific data types like `DataSet`.

Comment: You should also tell us what you mean by "does not seem to be effective"

Answer (score -1):

You can use Entity framework from nuget packages (built in visual studio) , it have default connector for ms sql , but you can also find for mysql & postgre sql. Then expose your services as REST which is language independent.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer )

Comment: SOAP isn't language independent?

Comment: Sure it is , but i believe working on REST will be more fun & JSON parsing is fast as comapre to XML